# Angular: Updating scope with factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angularfire

I'm currently having an issue with keeping my scopes updated using a factory service and AngularFire. I think the code speaks for itself:

```
//Creates firebase object based on URL ($stateParams as an ID)
jobControllers.factory('Job', getJobService);
function getJobService($firebaseObject, $stateParams) {
   var ref = new Firebase("<my firebase url>" + $stateParams.jobId);
       return $firebaseObject(ref);
}

//Sets Scope to firebase object in getJobService
jobControllers.controller('JobCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Job) {
    $scope.job = Job;
});
```

This works fine, when you click a link like /jobs/:jobId/ it loads the proper data. The problem is once you go back to /jobs/ and click another :jobId the data remains the same. I am fairly certain the issue is that my firebase URL is staying the same and $stateParams isn't changing on controller load so the data uses the URL For the first item clicked. If this is the case, how can I change my factory to take a parameter so I can pass the correct updated $stateParams to it in the controller?

I previously did not have this problem when I had called my firebase objects inside the controller as such:

```
jobControllers.controller('JobCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $stateParams, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase("<my firebase url>" + $stateParams.jobId);
  $scope.job = $firebaseObject(ref);
});
```

My reasoning for using a factory is because I did not like how I was defining the firebase URLs in every different controller, so I wanted to create a reusable service for such. If there is a better way - please advise.

**edit:** Figured it out thanks to charlieftl

```
function getFireBaseService($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
  return {
    getArray: function(url) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com" + url);
      return $firebaseArray(ref);
    },
    getObject: function(url) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com" + url);
      return $firebaseObject(ref);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the factory is a singleton and only initializes once. Your approach will only use whatever value `$stateParams.jobId` is when it does initialize

Use a function to return the firebase object so that it will be run each time it is called upon

```
function getJobService($firebaseObject, $stateParams) {

    function getJob() {
        var ref = new Firebase("<my firebase url>" + $stateParams.jobId);
        return $firebaseObject(ref);    
    }
    //return object from factory
    return {
        getJob: getJob
    }
}
```

Then in controller

```
 $scope.job = Job.getJob();
```